# Join Excel-Table with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, oledb, adodb

My excel-sheet is connected with the data of the sql-server. My clients shall be able to write some columns back to the sql server. The excel-filenames are variable, but the sheeetname and the columns are always static. I tried it with a button and vba but it ends up in error:

> Syntaxerror (missing operator) in queryexpression 'UPDATE hbs  SET lieferinfo_prio_neu = xlsx.liefer_prio_neu  FROM [Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=myserver;Database=mydb;UID=myuser;PWD=mypass;].[tbl_haka_base_size] hbs  JOIN [Tabelle3$] xlsx    ON xlsx.Artikelnummer'

The internal excel-sheetname is 'Tabelle3', the custom-name is 'Hakabase':

[image]

I tried both names without any result.

My code:

```
Dim excelConn As String
Dim sqlServerConn As String
Dim sqlCommand As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

excelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
           & ThisWorkbook.FullName _
           & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

sqlServerConn = "[Provider=SQLOLEDB;" _
                & "Data Source=myserver;" _
                & "Database=mydb;" _
                & "UID=ymuser;PWD=mypass;]"

sqlCommand = "UPDATE hbs " _
        & " SET lieferinfo_prio_neu = xlsx.liefer_prio_neu " _
        & " FROM " & sqlServerConn & ".[tbl_haka_base_size] hbs " _
        & " JOIN [Tabelle3$] xlsx " _
        & "   ON xlsx.Artikelnummer=hbs.artikelnummer"


Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open excelConn
conn.Execute sqlCommand
```

I've also tried to connect to the sqlserver + join the excel-data via openrowset but the server disallowed that:

```
        & " JOIN OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', " _
        & "     'Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" _
        &       ThisWorkbook.FullName & "', 'SELECT * FROM [Tabelle3$]') xlsx" _
```

> Installable ISAM not found

I think I have to create a linked server for each file and enable 'InProcess' for those files. This is not possible because the files are variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative solution which is a little bit slow so I still hope someone else is able to answer my question.

The alternative solution is to iterate through each row.. The file got about 150.000 rows and just for 10.000 rows I am waiting about 10 minutes..

Here is the part of iterating

```
    For Each range In sheet.rows: Do

    'Continue on headline
    If range.Row = 1 Or range.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Exit Do
    End If


    If Len(sheet.Cells(range.Row, lieferInfoColumnIndex)) > 0 Then
        articleNumber = sheet.Cells(range.Row, artNoColumnIndex)
        UpdateDatabase (articleNumber)
        savings = savings + 1
    End If

    Loop While False: Next range
```

Here is the slow update function for each row:

```
Private Sub UpdateDatabase(articleNumber As String)

Dim sqlServerConn As String
Dim sqlCommand As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection


sqlServerConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" _
                & "Data Source=myserver;" _
                & "Database=mydb;" _
                & "UID=myuser;PWD=mypass;"

sqlCommand = "UPDATE hbs " _
            & "SET lieferinfo_prio_neu=NULL " _
            & "FROM [TBL_HAKA_BASE] hbs " _
            & "WHERE Artikelnummer=" + articleNumber

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open sqlServerConn
conn.Execute sqlCommand
End Sub
```